# FB.login Error in Internet Explorer

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, share

I am using connect-js (FB.login) to login users to share my page, in standard way. In all normal browsers (chrome, firefox, opera) it pops up a window with permissions request (everything is fine). But in Internet Explorer (7 and 8, didn't test in 6) it pops up window that says: "An error occurred with [myapp]. Please try again later."

This is my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script language="javascript">
var nombre = "";
var pic_big = "";

FB.init({
    appId       :   '161599150607341', // App ID
    channelUrl  :   '//emocionesverde.com/channel.html', // Channel File
    status      :   true, // check login status
    cookie      :   true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml       :   true  // parse XFBML
});

function conectarse() {
    FB.login(handleSessionResponse, {
        scope: 'publish_stream, user_about_me'
    });
}

function handleSessionResponse(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            //console.log(response.name);
            window.nombre = response.name;
            getUserPic(response.id);
        });
    }
}

function getUserPic(uid) {
    FB.api('/me?fields=picture&type=large', function(response) {
        //console.log(response.picture);
        window.pic_big = response.picture;
        publicar();
    });
}

function publicar() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'stream.publish',
        message: '',
        attachment: {
            name: 'Emoción es Verde',
            caption: window.nombre + '  midió el impacto de sus acciones verdes. Te invitamos a conocer acciones para mantener el planeta verde con Emoción es Verde',
            media: [{
                type: 'flash',
                swfsrc: 'http://mainteractivetools.com/erik/mifb/emocionesverde/Prueba.swf?pic=' + window.pic_big + '&nombre=' + window.nombre,
                imgsrc: 'http://mainteractivetools.com/erik/mifb/emocionesverde/telefonica1.jpg',
                expanded_width: '450',
                expanded_height: '258'
            }],

            href: 'http://www.emocionesverde.com'

        },
        action_links: [{
            text: 'Emoción es Verde',
            href: 'http://www.emocionesverde.com'
        }],
        user_message_prompt: 'Escribe un comentario'
    }, function (response) {});
}

$('#swfmapsdiv').css('visibility', 'hidden');
</script>
```

---

Comment: an error always occured with IE...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding p3p headers? It's an IE thing and clears up a lot of problems. However cryptic the codes are. What Facebook is essentially trying to do is share cookies across domains, which is a security flag. You need to say it's ok.

Comment: yeah, what Brent said  :) See here for a detailed explanation of p3p headers http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx

Comment: tks, i try to set the p3p and after do that i´m back to share my coments.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be in channelUrl, try to have the whole path there i.e http://emocionesverde.com/channel.html

Also login into facebook as app developer - the error message will be more detailed